# Converting variables to observations in SAS

Tags: arrays, variables, sas

I have the following homework question in SAS.  I am given twelve variables, each with a single observation (they are in an excel spreadsheet), and my assignment  is to convert them into a single variable with twelve observations *without* use of proc transpose.  This seems like it should be a simple exercise in records management, using arrays, but neither me nor my classmates can figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you have read the excel data into a SAS data set, this looks like a data step exercise. Put all of the variables into an array (look up the ARRAY statement in SAS documentation). Loop over the array with a DO loop, setting your new variable equal to the array variable and outputting a row in each iteration of the DO loop. Can help further if you give this a try on your own and you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Look through some of the other Stack Overflow questions in [tag:sas] with `transpose` keyword.  Some of them will show exactly this method.

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/widetolong_data.htm

Answer (score -1):

You can concatenate all variable and assign value to required variable.

Comment: Improve this answer by adding an example or some code.